# Extract case-insensitive query parameter from URL

Tags: url, go, request.querystring, querystringparameter

I am trying to extract the case-insensitive query parameter `/staging/ec/23463/front-view-72768.jpg?angle=90&or=0x0&wd=400&ht=200` from the URL. When I try to convert the whole URL in lowercase it throws the following exception :

```
cannot use r.URL (type *url.URL) as type string in argument to strings.ToLower
```

I printed the value of URL which says underlying it stores all the query strings as map i.e. `map[angle:[90] or:[0x0] wd:[400] ht:[200]]`. Hence I will get the correct value using this `r.URL.Query().Get("or")` But if query string comes out `Or`. It will fail.

Comment: You haven't included the code you're having problems with, but the error message should make the solution pretty obvious: You need to operate on a string, not on a `url.URL`.

Answer (score 6):

*URL.Query() returns a value of type url.Values, which is just a `map[string][]string` with a few extra methods.

Since URL values are by definition case-sensitive, you will have to access the map directly.

```
var query url.Values

for k, vs := range query {
    if strings.ToLower(k) == "ok" {
        // do something with vs
    }
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/7YVuxI3GO6X

Answer (score 0):

```
cannot use r.URL (type *url.URL) as type string in argument to strings.ToLower
```

This is because you are passing `ur.URL` instead of `string`. Get the string from url through `String()` function.

```
url.String()
```